# Building nested directories using makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, mkdir

I tried to build a nested directories following: [Iterating through a list of directories in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624236/iterating-through-a-list-of-directories-in-a-makefile)

Here is my script

```
LAYER1 = a b 
LAYER2 = 1 2 

$(LAYER1)/foo%/run: $(DIR)
       mkdir -p $@

DIR: $(addsuffix /foo$(LAYER2)/run, $(LAYER1))
```

The expected output is creating a/foo1/run a/foo2/run b/foo1/run b/foo2/run but the output is only 1 directory named a. How do I create the expected directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See MadScientist's answer as to why your answer would not work.   As far as something that will work, you likely want code that looks like this:

```
LAYER1 = a b 
LAYER2 = 1 2

DIRS := $(foreach L1,$(LAYER1),\
           $(foreach L2,$(LAYER2),\
              $(L1)/foo$(L2)/run))

all: | $(DIRS)

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Notice the use of [order-only dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) as the prerequisite type for `$(DIRS)`

Answer (score 3):

What does the rule:

```
$(LAYER1)/foo%/run: $(DIR)
```

expand to?  It expands to this:

```
a b/foo%/run: $(DIR)
```

(I don't know what `$(DIR)` is supposed to be) which is an explicit rule that tells make how to build two things: `a` and `b/foo%/run` (this is not a pattern rule because not all the targets contain `%`).

Since `a` here is the first target in the makefile, it's the one that will be run by default when you run `make`.

What does `$(addsuffix /foo$(LAYER2)/run, $(LAYER1))` do?  It takes every word in `$(LAYER1)` and prefixes it by the string `/foo$(LAYER2)/run`.  What is that string?  It's `/foo1 2/run`.  So the result of this is:

```
a/foo1 2/run b/foo1 2/run
```

which means `DIR` has the files `a/foo1`, `2/run`, `b/foo1`, and `2/run` as dependencies.

If `LAYER1` has multiple words you need to loop through it, not just use it as-is.